# Bootstrap column being pushed to different width

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a new theme for my web blog, but I ran into a small issue:
The panel which I use for the post itself gets pushed wider than I want.

This is how I want it to look

[image: This is how I want it to look]

(screenshot from the posts list).

When I use *nearly* the same code (with only one different WordPress function (`the_content()` instead of `get_the_content()`), then this is how it ends up.

[image: This is how it ends up]

As you can see, it's not right, but I don't know how to fix it.
I do know that there are some words in the post that do not go to a new line in time, causing the issue.

I hope somebody will help me :D
Cheers

Edit: 
Here is the code:
Working index.php: pastebin.com/YjtknwZe

I couldn't post more than 2 links, so see my comment below

Comment: Can you please post the code too?

Comment: Oh yea sure hold on I forgot to add it :)  (gonna edit the main post)

Comment: problematic single.php: http://pastebin.com/WewEjkwL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure should be:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left col-md-9" id="main">
        ..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The custom "wrapper" and lack of a `row` outside the columns are causing the problem. [Read the Bootstrap grid docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> -Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
>   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

***and..***

> Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns. Content should be placed
>   within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Comment: Removing the custom "wrapper" didn't do anything but breaking my footer, however, adding another `.row` between the `.wrapper` and the `.col` made it work :)